# C - Appending new data to linked list changes the previous data, too

Tags: c, variables, pointers, memory, linked-list

I am new to C and have stumbled upon a problem I hope you can help me with.

We have a double linked list

```
struct LinkedList {
    LinkedListNode *first;
    LinkedListNode *last;
};
```

and the nodes which are elements therein

```
struct LinkedListNode {
    LinkedListNode *previous;
    LinkedListNode *next;
    char *data;
};
```

Trying to append elements to the list, I wrote a function which creates a node at the end of the list with the given data.

```
void append(LinkedList *list, char *data)
```

It works properly if I call the function like this:

```
append(list, "abc");
append(list, "def");
```

Which leads to the linked list containing 2 nodes - the first one with data being `"abc"` and the second one with data being `"def"`.

However, if I pass the data as a variable, for example with

```
char testData[10] = "";
strcpy(testData, "abc");
append(list, testData);
strcpy(testData, "def");
append(list, testData);
```

The result is 2 linked list nodes both with the data `"def"`.

The reason for it probably is that the data pointer inside the first and second node both point to the same memory, however, I don't know how to change this fact or how to circumvent it.

The code where I pass the data inside the function looks like this:

```
struct LinkedListNode *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedListNode));
newNode->data = data;
```

I hope you can help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: `LinkedListNode *previous;` LinkedListNode is not defined. (are you using a C++ compiler to compile C code?)

Comment: @wildplasser
I'm using the compiler from Visual Studio. 
So far the program has been working. Can the way I wrote the structure cause problems later on?

Comment: Yes: the program won't compile if you use a real C compiler.

Comment: I just had a look, it is defined in a header file. 
Thanks nonetheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list is only storing a *pointer* to the data. In the first example those pointers to string literals are different, but in the second example, they all point to the same place, where the data is changing.

Perhaps you can try such as

```
char testData[10] = "";
strcpy(testData, "abc");
append(list, strdup(testData));
strcpy(testData, "def");
append(list, strdup(testData));
```

but remember that `strdup` allocates memory which will need to be freed later.

An alternative is to duplicate the string within the function, though will create redundancy if a string is passed that is already unique.

```
newNode->data = strdup(data);
```

Although the function `strdup` is in many libraries, it is non standard, but easy to create your own (thanks David Bowling).

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that `strdup()` is nonstandard, though easy to implement if needed.

Comment: @Weather
It worked, thanks. 
Let's assume I don't want to change the way I pass values to the function, but the function itself.
Would 
`newNode->data = strdup(data);`
instead of
`newNode->data = data;`
work?
I tried it right away but for some reason visual studio is still in the process of linking.

Comment: @Weather and David
Thank you both! This problem has been plaguing me for quite some time.